# iOS app 64bits after Feb 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6

Today I tried submitting app to appStore.app is submitted successfully with no error or warning. When I go to iTunes it says Invalid binary.

I have setup my project as 64 bits still I can't get submitted.
[image: Here is my project settings]

In email from apple it says Missing 64-bit support

I am just wondering wether I am doing right way or not? Where exactly the problem is?

Comment: Make sure `Build Active Architecture Only` is set to `NO` for release builds.

Comment: I am gonna try right away. May be you are right because documentation says it should support both 32bits and 64bits.

Comment: @Dave Wood Awesome!!! Perfect. Its working. It is submitted. Thanks man for helping